# Different types of variables with the same name into a function

Tags: java, android-activity

I have this code and I'm wondering if it is possible to do something like that:

```
    switch (typeActivity) {
    case 0:
        Type1Activity aux=activity1;
        break;
    case 1:
        Type2Activity aux=activity2;
        break;
    case 2:
        Type3Activity aux=activity3;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Great thanks to you in advance.

Comment: should case 2 be `Type3Activity` instead of `Tipe3Activity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming from the similar names of your types they extend a baseclass called something like TypeActivity, or at least should do it this way ;)
Then you could use:

```
TypeActivity aux = null;

switch (typeActivity) {
  case 0:
    aux = activity1;//Type1Activity
    break;
  case 1:
    aux = activity2;//Type2Activity
    break;
  case 2:
    aux = activity3;//Type3Activity
    break;
  default:
    break;
}
```

Only other way would be using Object as Class `Object aux = null;` which i wouldn´t recommend since it seems polymorphism / extends are the correct way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Type1Activity aux = null;


switch (typeActivity) {
    case 0:
        aux=activity1;
        break;
    case 1:
        aux=activity2;
        break;
    case 2:
        aux=activity3;
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, the scope of a variable declared within a switch statement is the whole switch statement. So your code should generate a compile error ("variable aux is already defined", or something like that).

Besides, you never use those variables so the whole code is pointless. If this is a simplification of an actual use case, you should explain in more details what you are trying to achieve.